# Curl function not working when proxy enabled

Tags: php, curl

I am using wamp server 2.0. Curl function is working fine when i connect to the internet without proxy. But when I use an internet connection with proxy settings enabled, curl function is not working and i am getting the message "cannot execute".

here is the code I have used.

```
<?php
function get_data($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 $data =curl_exec($ch)or die(curl_errno($ch).":Cannot execute");
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('ssdp.kerala.gov.in');
echo $returned_content;

?>
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that proxy in your curl initialization:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '11.22.33.44:88');
```